# Return from closure?

Tags: javascript, closures

How does one return from a closure, without returning from the containing function?

In the following function, the `return` statement actually returns from `GM_xmlhttpRequest`: not the closure. Naturally I can see that I could arrange my code so that that execution drops off the end of the closure, but I'm curious as to how to early return in the example.

```
function GM_xmlhttpRequest(details, callback) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState != 4)
      return; // <-- zomg returns from parent function wtf
    if (xhr.status != 200)
      callback(null);
    callback(xhr);
  }
  xhr.open('GET', details.url, true);
  xhr.send();
};
```

Comment: there's no way that's correct, unless the parser is having issues due to skipping characters (`{`,`;`,etc). you are aware that `GM_xmlhttpRequest` is going to run and complete as soon as it's called, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*return* will only ever exit the *callee* (current function) and return control to the *caller* (calling "parent" function), it will never the return from the *caller*.  In the situation you describe, the *callee* is the anonymous function set to *onreadystatechange* and there is no caller (per se).

*GM_xmlhttpRequest* returns *undefined* after the `xhr.send()` line before the *onreadystatechange* function runs because there is no *return* statement and the XHR is asynchronous.  The "zomg wtf" line will just exit that anonymous function since there is no *caller* to pass control back to.

From ECMA-262, 3rd and 5th editions (section 12.9 The *return* statement):

> A return statement causes a function to cease execution and return a value to the
>   caller. If *Expression* is omitted, the return value is undefined. Otherwise, the return value is the value of *Expression*.

Comment: Adjusting the closure so it doesn't use return, results in the closure being called several times with different `readyState` values. The explicit return terminates the function prematurely, and no more calls are made.